# Find the condition for the collinearity of $3$ points in the parallelogram $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Consider the parallelogram $ABCD$ and the points $M \in AB$ and $N \in AC$ such that:

$$\vec{AM} = \dfrac{1}{x} \vec{AB} \hspace{3cm} \vec{AN} = \dfrac{1}{y} \vec{AC}$$

with $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$. We have to find a relation between $x$ and $y$ such that the points $D, N, M$ are collinear.

I don't know how to approach this. The result given in my textbook is $x = y - 1$, but no explanation is given.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{AB}=\vec{a}$ and $\vec{AD}=\vec{b}.$

Thus, there is $k$ for which:
$$\vec{MN}=k\vec{MB}$$ or
$$-\frac{1}{x}\vec{a}+\frac{1}{y}(\vec{a}+\vec{b})=k\left(-\frac{1}{x}\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right),$$ which gives
$$-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=-\frac{k}{x}$$ and
$$\frac{1}{y}=k$$ and from here
$$-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=-\frac{1}{xy}.$$
Can you end it now?